# call a function from external class unto the codeigniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this external class that I'm trying to call inside the codeigniter library class

Loader.php

```
<?php

namespace PDLoader;

class Loader{

    public function load($comp=false){

        if( $comp ){

            $comp = ucfirst($comp);

            if( !file_exists(__DIR__.'/modules/'.$comp.'/'.$comp.'.php') ){
                print_r('Component '.$comp.' not found.');
                return;
            }

            require_once(__DIR__.'/modules/'.$comp.'/'.$comp.'.php');

            $module = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' .$comp;

            return new $module;

        }
    }
}
```

and in my codeigniter library

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(__DIR__.'/../../../Loader/Loader.php');

$loader = new Loader;

class Loader{

    public function loadModule(){

        global $loader;

        $loader->load('basicwebsite')->appheader([]);
    }
}
```

yet it throws me this

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function load() on null

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the namespace when you create your loader:

```
$loader = new \PDLoader\Loader;
```

Comment: Also note that you can use `APPPATH` as the root of your `require_once` path to simplify the code and make it less fragile.